# Creating table with repeated field manually

Tags: sql, r, google-bigquery

I want to create the table in BigQuery (Legacy) in format below:

```
-- +---------+---------+
-- | Var1    | Var2    +
-- +---------+---------+
-- | x       | 1       +
-- |         | 2       +
-- |         | 3       +
-- | y       | 1       +
-- +---------+---------+
```

The code below can create the table manually row by row. I'm looking for code that specifies that values 1,2,3 belong to x in var1 etc.

```
SELECT SPLIT(Var1x) AS Var1 
FROM (SELECT 'x,y' AS Var1x)
```

Also maybe if there is a way how to transform columns into one repeated field could help. Something like you have y column and x1 - x5 columns and we can transform them into just one x repeated column. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: the question is if there is a way to do that...my code example could create a table manually row by row, but I don't know how I can specify that var2 is repeated column and values 1-2-3 belongs to var1 x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  Var1, NEST(Var2) AS Var2
FROM 
  (SELECT 'x' AS Var1, 1 AS Var2),
  (SELECT 'x' AS Var1, 2 AS Var2),
  (SELECT 'x' AS Var1, 3 AS Var2),
  (SELECT 'y' AS Var1, 1 AS Var2)
GROUP BY Var1
```

Please note - in order to preserve this structure - you need to chose `destination table` and check `allow large result` and uncheck `flatten results` in Web UI - otherwise BigQuery Legacy SQL automatically flattens most outter query output

Another way to verify above is to count number of rows (should be two and not four)

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
  SELECT 
    Var1, NEST(Var2) AS Var2
  FROM 
    (SELECT 'x' AS Var1, 1 AS Var2),
    (SELECT 'x' AS Var1, 2 AS Var2),
    (SELECT 'x' AS Var1, 3 AS Var2),
    (SELECT 'y' AS Var1, 1 AS Var2)
  GROUP BY Var1
)
```

While above does answer your original question  - I firmly suggest to use standard SQL - see respective version below:

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 'x' as Var1, [1,2,3] as Var2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'y', [1]
```